# Is all access to the underlying system components protected via an access control mechanism managed by the kernel?

Tags: kernel

I'm assuming it is possible for an attacker to bypass the Linux kernel to make changes to system memory, hard drives etc.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking exactly? Do you mean bypass security checks built into the kernel?

Comment: From my place of ignorance, I'm having trouble expressing what I'm asking exactly. I'm trying to understand the narrowest "choke point" for data access on a Linux system.

Comment: This question might be better worded: is all access to the underlying system components protected via an access control mechanism managed by the kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both main memory and disk drives are managed solely by the kernel.

- For a user space program to access these it needs the kernel's cooperation through the invocation of system calls.
- A kernel module can access them without further approval, because it's already part of the kernel. Of course to become a kernel module kernel cooperation is again required.

Comment: So what's the mechanism that enables the kernel to become the protector? Is there help from the CPU?

Comment: Yes, typically this kind of access protection is enforced by the CPU on the lowest level. You should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)#Functions_of_the_kernel and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)#Issues_of_kernel_support_for_protection for details.

Comment: Also I found this http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/cpu-rings-privilege-and-protection/